# Extend text box in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox, extend

I am trying to find an answer for this problem for a long time(i use winforms in c#).

I am looking for a control as in the picture, a text box with a down arrow when it has been clicked an extend text box is open, i do not want to make the text box bigger, i thought mabye it is a property of combobox but i couldnt find.

Does someone familiar with this control?
thx !
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uvvo.png

Comment: That is essentially a `TextBox` control displayed by the designer (I think it is technically the string collection editor control).  The unopened smaller element is usually readonly which would confuse users in normal contexts

Comment: ok ,do you know different solution ? one that gives the user option to get bigger edit space  but the original text box does not become bigger ? or just make the text box bigger and thats it

Comment: Do write a custom control.

Comment: Usually controls like the one you show are part of a larger PropertyGrid control and don't exist as a standalone "dropdown plus textbox" form.  A PropertyGrid typically has a default view and then an editor.  The editor is displayed when a property's value is focused.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct control, which can do this but here is a solution:

**1:** You create a combobox, add a "DropDown" and a "DropDownClosed" -event to it and set the DropDownHeight to 1

**2:** You create a textbox Underneath it, enable Multiline and set it's visibility to false.

**3:** In your Form.cs add this functions:

```
private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Visible = true;
    textBox1.Focus();
}

private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

**4:** If this works, you can create a usercontrol for it.